# Dropdown Menu doesn't appear when hovering & Category titles too small

Tags: html, css

I am quite new to html and css and I have a few issues with my project for uni. I want to create a dropdown menu, that only appears when being hovered over. I have followed a tutorial and did it the same way, however, it doesn't work for me...

Another thing that I don't really understand why it's happening is that my font in the nav bar (home, pottery, tutorials, shop) are not 20px even though I set it to that. And whenever I want to set it to something different (like waaay bigger) it doesn't apply the bigger font. What am I doing wrong? :(

Oh and one more thing! Why are my links in the first paragraph (Get Started, Plates,...) suddenly next to each other? They are supposed to be underneath each other...

That's a lot of questions, I know.. Thank you for any kind of help!

```css
body, html {
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 2400px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
  
body{
    font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    color: #A5A58D;
    background-image: url(file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Images/Pottery%20Website%20Background%20Blurred-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
      
.header1{
    height: 50px;
    padding: 50px 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 41px;
    text-transform:   uppercase;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after{
  clear:both;
}

.cf{
  zoom:1;
}

nav{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

li a{
  display: block;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #FFF1E6;
}

li a:hover, .category > li:hover > a{
  background: #AEAE98;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
}

.current, a:hover.current{
  background: #909072;
  color: #FFF1E6;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
  cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown{
  float: none;
  background: #FFF1E6;
  color: #B7B7A4;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -9000em;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-right: 0%;
}

ul.dropdown li{
  float: none;
}

.category li:hover ul{
  left: 0;
}

ul.dropdown li a{
  color: #B7B7A4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B7B7A4;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
} 

ul.dropdown li a:hover{
  background: #FFE8D6;
}

.header2{
    display: flex;
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20% 0 0 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #A5A58D;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20%;
}

.header3{
    font-size: 41px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-left: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1544px;
    left: 22%;
}
  
.textparagraphen1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 239px;
    right: 53%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #EDDCD2;
}


.textparagraphen2{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 999px;
    left: 53%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

.textparagraphen3{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 485px;
    height: 445px;
    background-color: #A5A58D;
    color: #EDDCD2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
        top: 1544px;
        right: 53%;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 23px;
    }

    .textparagraphen4{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; 
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 68.4%;
        height: 453px;
        background-color: #A5A58D;
        color: #EDDCD2;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
        top: 255px;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 23px;
    }

 

    .linksammlung{
        float: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        background: #A5A58D;
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #EDDCD2;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-transform:   uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    .abbildung1{
        position: absolute;
        left: 53%;
        top: 239px;
    }
      
    .abbildung2{
        position: absolute;
        right: 53%;
        top: 784px;
    }

    .abbildung3{
        position: absolute;
        left: 53%;
        top: 1544px;
    }

    .abbildung5{
        position: absolute;
        right: 53%;
        top: 1664px;
    }

    .abbildung6{
        position: absolute;
        left: 52.6%;
        top: 1664px;
    }

    .tutorialvideo{
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 808px;
}

.footerContainer {
    top: 2322px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
  
.footer{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A5A58D;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #A5A58D;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
  
.footer2{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A5A58D;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"> 


<head>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="WS 2020 Screendesign Unterseiten.css">


<title> ALINA'S POTTERY </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg-image"></div>
  <div class="header1"> Alina's Pottery </div>
  
  <nav class="categoryContainer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="category">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pottery.html" title="Pottery" class="category">Pottery</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="general.html" title="General" class="subCategory">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="handbuilding.html" title="Hand-Building" class="subCategory">Hand-Building</a></li>
        <li><a href="potterywheel.html" title="Pottery Wheel" class="subCategory">Pottery Wheel</a></li>
        <li><a href="materials.html" title="Materials" class="subCategory">Materials</a></li>
        <li><a href="temperatures.html" title="Temperatures" class="subCategory">Temperatures</a></li>
    </ul>   
    </li>

    <li class="current"><a href="tutorials.html" title="Tutorials" class="category">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="viewall.html" title="View All" class="subCategory">View All</a></li>
            <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="subCategory">Get Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="subCategory">Plates</a></li>
            <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="subCategory">Mugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="bowls.html" title="Bowls" class="subCategory">Bowls</a></li>
        </ul>   
        </li>
    <li><a href="shop.html" title="Shop" class="category">Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="textparagraphen4">
    <div class="header3"> 
    Tutorials
    </div>

    <div class="text6">
    These videos should give you a kick-start to pottery, explaining the basics,</br>
    clearing up common mistakes and offering inspiration for your future projects.</br>
    Pottery is actually super easy to learn - everybody can do it.</br>
    That’s why I want to give you all the tools to start out even as a total beginner.</br>
    </br>
    Follow these links to get to the different tutorials:</br>

    </div>

    <div class="links">

        <ol>
            <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="linksammlung"> GET STARTED</a></li>
            <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="linksammlung"> PLATES </a></li>
            <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="linksammlung"> MUGS </a></li>
            <li><a href="bowls.html" title="bowls" class="linksammlung"> BOWLS </a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="text 6">
    And always remember: imperfect ceramics are way better and more personal than perfect ones!
    </div>
</section>

<div class="tutorialvideo">
    <iframe width="70%" height="756px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JOko1ygjPwk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<section class="bildabschnitt2">
    <div class="abbildung5">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3626588/pexels-photo-3626588.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-daria-shevtsova-3626588.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Cupboard" width="622px" height="622px">
    </div>
    
    <div class="abbildung6">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4440217/pexels-photo-4440217.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-taryn-elliott-4440217.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Work Space" width="622px" height="622px">
    </div>
    
</section>

<div class="footerContainer">
    <a href="aboutme.html" title="About Me" class="footer">About Me</a>
    <a href="socials.html" title="Socials" class="footer"> Socials</a>
    <a href="imprint.html" title="Imprint" class="footer2">Imprint</a> 
</div>


</body>
  
  
<div class="bg-image"></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Submenu display

For your dropdown menu you don't have any rules to display it when hover first level link.

So you can add a rules like:

```css
.categoryContainer > ul > li:hover > .dropdown {
  left:0;
}
```

### 2. Font size navbar

You define a `font-size: 20px` for `nav` tag. But you also define `font-size:10px` to `a` tag. So rules for `a` tag erase `nav` rule.

You can add a more specific rules like below:

```css
nav a {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

### 3. Link in paragraph next to each other

Because you define rule for all `ul` and `li`, try to be more specific in your css rules

instead doing that:

```css
ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

do that:

```css
nav.categoryContainer ul, nav.categoryContainer li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

### Conclusion

Here is a codepen with updated code:
https://codepen.io/zecka/pen/ZEpjbVK

But i saw a lot of other problem in your code.

So pay attention to:

1. try to use class and be more specific on css rules
2. Avoid use fixed height for your element
3. Avoid absolute position when not necessary
4. ...

Comment: wow, thank you so much! :) this really helped a lot. There are so many small things that I don't see yet, but it's slowly coming together.

Comment: NP ! If this answer is ok for you you can mark it as accepted answer. But if you plan to develop a website,i strongly encourage you to continue to follow css tutorials before you start. Keep it up, you'll see you'll improve quickly.

Comment: yes it definitely did answer my questions! and I will definitely study more and watch tutorials :) however, one more just came up. Maybe you can help me with this one too. I want to center the dropdown menu items underneath the corresponding nav bar items. Can you tell me how to do this? :)

Comment: I just solved it! I set the width of the dropdown menu to 125% and now it looks the way I want it to look :)

Answer (score 0):

try to add these into your stylesheet

```
.categoryContainer ul li:nth-child(2):hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: inherit;
}

ol {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

1. hovering problem:

you are selecting the incorrect element (to style)
the first part li a:hover, it means you are trying to add style to the a, while in fact, you are tring to style the ul
the second part is pretty much the same

2. font size in nav

the anchors are not inheriting

3. elements sitting side by side

you may want to take a look CSS "display" property, should these be block? inline? inline-block?
I think display: flex is easiler to handle.